# How to get the original request URI in api gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

From a lambda implemented api gateway resource, how to get the original request URI. Or even just the original path?

Lacking a better way I'm currently using the following three variables that I pass down to the lambda using the default request template:

```
$context.resourcePath   contains the path with variable names   ex: "/blah/{var}"
$input.params().path    contains the variable names and values  ex: {"var":"something"}
$context.stage          contains the stage                      ex: "prod"
```

That's quite a hassle since it requires path variable substitution to get the original call path:

```
/prod/blah/something
```

How can I get the original URL or URI?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not finding anything in the documentation that lets you get the original call URI.  I can add a feature request to consider adding it.  Can you describe your use case.  Why do you want to get the original URI?

Comment: We're using a key+secret pair to sign each request. The algorithm is similar to the aws signature version 4, the request path is one of the elements the client must hash. So the service needs the original request path to validate the signature.

Comment: It looks like we already have a feature request to add this.  I've added this post as a +1 to the request.

Comment: @MikeDatAWS I have another use case. There is a service that acts as a proxy for some third-party API. It modifies some headers but has to know _the exact_ URI requested which may include urlencoded characters. E.g. `/some-resource/abc%2Fdef`. When using REST or HTTP API events, only normalized path is passed to lambda, e.g. `/some-resource/abc/def` which does not work when passed to the mentioned third-party API.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 'workaround'.

If you create a custom domain name with a BasePathMapping, and call the API using this custom domain, the original request uri actually has your stage name in there:

Call directly to the API gateway:

```
curl -v 'https://some-id.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/ping'
...
request.url: https://some-id.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ping'
```

But if we call it through te custom domain (which is actually a cloudfront distribution):

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.our.domain.name.com/v1/ping
...
request.url: https://api.our.domain.name.com/v1/ping
```

In my opinion, the direct call gives you an INCORRECT request url in the lambda function, as the url very clearly has the stage name in there.

This breaks the routing middleware of at least flask.

Any update on the feature request?